# vue3: in promise type error while using innerHTML

Tags: vuejs3, innerhtml

i'm trying to use innerHTML in vue. but get the error: caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

here is my code in App.vue:

```
data () {
return {

}

},


mounted() {

async function getData () {

var domein = 'mydomain';

  var slots = document.querySelectorAll('*[class^="prefix-"]')

  var list = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < slots.length; i++){
    
    if ('cms-' === slots[i].className.split(" ")[0].substring(0, 7)) {
    list += slots[i].className.split(" ")[0] + ',';
    }
  }

  const res = await fetch(domein + '/response.php?slots=' + list)
  const data = await res.json()

  for (var y = 0; y < data.length; y++){
  var slot = document.querySelector("*[class*=" + data[y].classname + "]")
  slot.innerHTML = data[y].content
  }
}

window.onload = function(){
getData();
};
}

}
```

How can i resolve this error? i used an v-if with slot and data in it.  i used nextTick, it also didn't work?? i replaced .innerHTML for .value, dont work either?. anybody some suggestions?

Comment: `document.querySelector` did not return any elements.  have you inspected and verified `data[y].classname` matches any class names in the actual DOM?  It's generally bad practice in Vue to use document querying.  Vue manages the DOM so any manipulation of it needs to be done very carefully and only if you can't somehow achieve what you want with normal Vue best practices such as using [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html) instead of querySelector and [v-html](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html) instead of setting innerHTML.

Comment: thanks for your reply yoduh!  this script works fine in a 'normal' html page. so.. yes the queryselector returns matching elements.